# URL to treeview

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I'm trying to fill the treeview with the links.

I have this array:

```
String[] Paths = {
          "Home/Girls/Smoll",
          "Home/Girls/Pige",
          "Home/Girls/Manually",
          "Home/Man/Smoll",
          "Home/Man/Pige",
          "index/domain/index",
          "index/ur"
};
```

I have do it like what I want be coded it:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/YAoSTp0.jpg]

But my problem is the array is not constant, maybe changes to another value.

Comment: Use `String.Split()` to split the string on `/`, then iterate the array and check in de nodes exists. If not, add them.

Comment: You need to show what you've done, Stack Overflow doesn't exist to write your code for you I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a recursive algorithm

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication24
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            string[] Paths = {
                "Home/Girls/Smoll",
                "Home/Girls/Pige",
                "Home/Girls/Manualy",
                "Home/Man/Smoll",
                "Home/Man/Pig",
                "index/domain/index",
                "index/ur"
            };
            List<List<string>> splitPaths = Paths.Select(x => x.Split(new char[] { '/' }).ToList()).ToList();
            TreeNode node = new TreeNode();
            RecursiveAdd(splitPaths, node);
            treeView1.Nodes.Add(node);
            treeView1.ExpandAll();
        }
        public void RecursiveAdd(List<List<string>> splitPaths, TreeNode node)
        {
            var groups = splitPaths.GroupBy(x => x[0]).ToList();
            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                TreeNode childNode = node.Nodes.Add(group.Key);
                List<List<string>> children = group.Where(x => x.Count() > 1).Select(x => x.Skip(1).ToList()).ToList();
                RecursiveAdd(children, childNode);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you ! that's work ! and all your code is clarity but this | 
 " var groups = splitPaths.GroupBy(x => x[0]).ToList(); " 

Can you explain it

Comment: I'm grouping by the current root folder names.  Later in the code I remove the root when getting the children by using x.skip(1).   So initially the first two groups would be Home and index.